# Fish School Search (косяк рыб) для решения задачи коммивояжера

Tags: оптимизация

Мне необходимо использовать алгоритм поиска **косяком рыб** для решения задачи **коммивояжера**
*(наверняка есть алгоритмы, которые справятся с этой задачей лучше, чем FSS, но нужно именно им)*.

Я поверхностно ознакомлен с этим алгоритмом: «рыбехи» плавают, ищут экстремум функции, по выполнению алгоритма можно засечь позиции рыб и отследить экстремум.

На скриншоте отображение позиций рыб после работы алгоритма на примере функции Ackley.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В задаче коммивояжера же мы должны оптимизировать сумму евклидовых расстояний, нужно считать что задача замкнутая.

Код я, конечно же, не прошу. Был бы рад, если бы Вы поделились **идеей** модификации алгоритма FSS для решения задачи коммивояжера. *(в интернете абсолютно ничего об этом нет, или же я плохо искал)*

Comment: Начните с определения положения рыбы. Как описать её координаты в терминах задачи?